# Is there an event receiver in SQL database

Tags: sql-server, database, events, sharepoint

Is there an event receiver in SQL database/table, wherein if there is an update to any column in a table, it will trigger an event.

For example, I have a page in sharepoint, then everytime the table has been updated, then it will show the details.

This is like an event receiver for a sharepoint doclib and list, instead it is in a table.

Answer (score 0):

A. You should not alter SharePoints databases. 
B. If you want an 'event receiver' for a non-SharePoint database you could look in to sql-triggers. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)